# write an SQL query to display the username of the customer who has purchased a product most recently

Tags: mysql

write an SQL query to display the username of the customer who has purchased a product most recently

I am stuck on this query

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please **always** include your server version (e.g. MySQL 5.7) either with a tag or in the body of the question! Also, please provide the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders\G` and the same for `customer` (or whatever you've called the tables) - any other relevant tables also if you don't have a simple `FOREIGN KEY` relationship between the `orders` and the `customer` tables. As it stands, without this information, the question is likely to be closed!

Answer (score 1):

to get the most recent order:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
ORDER BY order_date DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

join the order table with the user table to get the username

```
SELECT users.user_name 
FROM users, orders 
WHERE orders.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY orders.order_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```